# distance between cards and bring image to front android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to have book shelves in my application, so I used cards view, but I can not decrease the distance between the cards from the sides.
everything I try changes the distance from the top and bottom.

this is the CardView xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="180dp"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
cardview:cardElevation="0dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shelf_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shelf" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#2d2d2d"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/v_pink"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/book_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the recycler view defined like this:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and in the activity -

```
 mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
 mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
```

eventually it looks like this:

[image]

I want the cards to be **close to each other from the sides** so it will look like one long shelf...

plaease  any help??

also if someone knows how do i put the first ImageView ("book_img") in front of the second ("shelf_img") it will be awesome... the only way i succeeded now is one above the second

**edit** : i succeeded this one with RelativeLayout

thanks!

Comment: "how do i put the first ImageView ("book_img") in front of the second" Try changing your orientation on the container to horizontal.

Comment: Have you tried changing  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" to  android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"?

Comment: @BakonJarser i tried, its the margin inside the card not between 2 cards

Comment: @BakonJarser the horizontal links the 2 images to the top and i cant put one below another (below not behind...)

Comment: please add a root xml for cardview, the values to change should be there (elevation, margin etc)

Comment: @Vendetta8247 it was deleted from some reason, i added it now:)